# Max flow with vertex capacities without reduction

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, max-flow, ford-fulkerson

I am trying to implement max-flow with vertex capacities in addition to edge's capacities.
I found in wiki a reduction to a new graph G where each vertex corresponds to v_in and v_out and some appropriate changes to the edges .
*My initial implementation did something else and I am wondering if it is wrong .*
In the step that the original ford-fulkerson examines a path it increases the flow of the path with respect to the edge of minimum capacity in this path (we cannot exceed that).
**What if I also found the minimum vertex capacity in this path ?** The largest between these quantities (`max(b(v)) and max(b(e)) for v and e in path p`) would define the maximum flow that can run through that path , wouldn't it ?
And the complexity remains the same .

Comment: Consider a vertex with more than two edges.

Comment: Sounds like one could construct a detailed bisimulation argument, so yes, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of graph algorithms are described in terms of making a new graph, but then in practical implementations we try to optimize that step away.

That sounds like what you're doing:  Does every augmenting path that you find in your flow graph correspond to a valid augmenting path in the (now imaginary) new graph?  If so, then your algorithm is fine.

Comment: i am not sure I get the answer.. Can you elaborate a little bit more ?  I am not making another graph , I am just checking each augmenting path for minimum edge capacity and minimum vertex capacity and i keep the min of those

Comment: Well, how do you know that reduction algorithm even works?  The new graph corresponds to the original graph, and a valid flow in the new graph corresponds to a valid flow in the original graph, including vertex capacities.  When you find an augmenting path in the original graph, there is a corresponding augmenting path in the new graph.  Is it valid?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason to use split node technique is because most of the time max-flow algorithms are used as a `black box` You don't want to change the algorithm implementation that's why you split the nodes.

Your algorithm is definitely correct.